# the fragments inside an activity are not being removed when I finish the activity

Tags: android

the fragments inside an activity are not being removed when I finish the activity
I have tried a bunch of things and I don't know what is wrong

- I have removed the fragment one by one in onBack button and it didn't work

  ```
  if(getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() > 0) {

   for (Fragment activeFragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {

          getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(activeFragment);
      }

      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();

  }
  ```
- this activity is created inside a webview I removed, cleaned cache...  but this didn't work either

  ```
  public void destroyWebView() {

  // Make sure you remove the WebView from its parent view before doing anything.
  _webview.removeAllViews();

  _webview.clearHistory();

  // NOTE: clears RAM cache, if you pass true, it will also clear the disk cache.
  // Probably not a great idea to pass true if you have other WebViews still alive.
  _webview.clearCache(true);

  // Loading a blank page is optional but will ensure that the WebView isn't doing anything when you destroy it.


  _webview.onPause();
  _webview.removeAllViews();
  _webview.destroyDrawingCache();

  // NOTE: This pauses JavaScript execution for ALL WebViews,
  // do not use if you have other WebViews still alive.
  // If you create another WebView after calling this,
  // make sure to call mWebView.resumeTimers().
  _webview.pauseTimers();

  // NOTE: This can occasionally cause a segfault below API 17 (4.2)
  _webview.destroy();

  // Null out the reference so that you don't end up re-using it.
  _webview = null;
  }
  ```

I put this function inside ondestroy() from the webview

the main activity has this has three tabs(fragments) also and dialog fragment, also I am using intent filter

any ideas?

Comment: "the fragments inside an activity are not been removed when I finish the activity" -- what does "not been removed" mean, and how have you determined this?

Comment: because the new fragments have information from the previous ones. I would like to press on back button and have the fragments clean when I come back to the activity

Comment: If by "have the fragments clean when I come back to the activity", you mean "have the fragment be clean when I start a new instance of this activity", then probably the problem lies in how your fragments are getting data, not that they have "not been removed". If by "have the fragments clean when I come back to the activity", you mean "when I return to this already-existing activity, I want the fragments to be clean", that is not how activities or fragments work.

Comment: Regardless, the code in your question does not really help anyone, because it does not depict your problem. Your [mcve] should be showing the fragments, how you are navigating to and from the activity with the fragments, and explaining in detail what data they fragments have in the new activity instance that you are not expecting.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I will pay attention to your comments

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, What do you mean when you said you created the activity inside the webview. In android, any view you use must be embedded into an activity not the other way round, and if you use a fragment, they are attached to the activity

Comment: thanks  @CommonsWare, I looked into  "how your fragments are getting data" and you were right the fragments weren't the problem. I got to solve the issue